# Handling TimeoutException when receiving messages asynchronously from MessageSession

Tags: c#, azure, multitasking, servicebus

Currently, my solution involves 1 Web and 1 Worker roles, "talking" each other through Azure Service Bus:

- Web role sends messages to "Request" queue.
- Worker takes messages from "Request" queue, do some work and place response messages to "Response" queue, from where they are taken by the Web role.
- Each request message sent by Web role, has to find your response, that's why I'm "marking" each request message with unique correlation identifier. Worker takes this identifier from request and "mark" the response with it.

Initially, I'm sending bunch of messages:

```
var messages = tasksForExecution.Select(s =>
            {
                var message = new BrokeredMessage(s);
                message.Properties.Add("action", "submit");
                message.ReplyToSessionId =  Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
                return message;
            }).ToList();
var correlationIdentifiers = messages.Select(x => x.ReplyToSessionId).ToList();
messages.ForEach(message => _requestQueueClient.SendAsync(message));
```

Getting the response:

```
var sessions = correlationIdentifiers
            .Select(x=>_responseQueueClient.AcceptMessageSession(x)).ToList();
var receiveMessageTasks = sessions.Select(session => session.ReceiveAsync()).ToList();
var allReadyTask = Task.WhenAll(receiveMessageTasks).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                ...extract data from result...
            }
..........
..........
allReadyTask.Wait();
```

As you can see, I'm creating bunch of tasks and when all of them are completed, a callback is invoked to extract some data. But what happens if an exception arises in one the the tasks? -> This exception is captured and when `Wait()` is called it is given to us. Since, the default timeout of `ReceiveAsync()` method is 1 min, it is highly possible to receive TimeoutException, because worker may finish its job later and no message for this session will exists in the queue. I found many examples, where people catch this type of exception, consume it, and try again the receive - they give another minute of time to worker to finish the job. How can I accomplish this in my scenario. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my resolution of the question. Please refer to the previous post in order to find out variables.

```
var receiveMessageTasks = sessions.Select(ReceiveMessageAsync).ToList();
var allReadyTask = Task.WhenAll(receiveMessageTasks).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            ...extract data from result...
        }
allReadyTask.Wait();
```

where `receiveMessageTasks` method is as follows:

```
private async Task<BrokeredMessage> ReceiveMessageAsync(MessageSession session)
    {
        BrokeredMessage message = null;

        // We can specify dead line for processing, but since our worker will return error message if a problem arise,
        // I prefer to wait endlessly
        // var timesToRetry = 0;

        // if Receive operation throws an exception, then message will be null
        while (message == null /* && timesToRetry < 5*/)
        {
            try
            {
                var task = session.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await task;
                message = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                //timesToRetry++;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // session was idle for a long time and azure closed it -> renew it
                session = _responseQueueClient.AcceptMessageSession(session.SessionId);
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Please, watch out for `ConfigureAwait(false)`. [Here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) you can find a description of the problem :)